# Whitespace on right side of wordpress gallery-columns-6

Tags: wordpress, gallery, whitespace

I have this white space on right-hand side of this wordpress website - but it just shows up with a  gallery-columns-6.

With a gallery 4 is ok, with gallery 5 also ok, etc.

**live link** : https://www.magykporto.com/photo/

Already tried with NO custom.css and no style.css , problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element is defined to be 16% in width, 6 x 16% = 96% that's why you have white space.  I works for the other gallery columns because 100% is evenly dividable by the numbers 5 and 4.

Add this CSS to fix the gallery item widths to be 16.666% reocurring.

```
#gallery-2 .gallery-item {
    width: 16.666% !important;
}
```